# Magento2 info inserted from custom module how to find?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

In the cart page for the products as well as order confirmation mail I get some additional info for example -

Details

`vendor name: name`

I want to get rid of this text, I have run through most of the pages in the module to find from where it is injected. 
also looked into the plugins for the related module, but didn't get any relevant info.

Also I enabled the front-end template and block hints but for that part I don't get an hint.

How I can find the info, I have run out of Idea, how to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

Run command in console: Just change directory where you want to search and text 'vendor name: name' (you can trim text if you don't find anything, Capitol letters are recognized)

```
grep -rnw '/your/magento/path/app/' -e 'vendor name: name'
```

This will wind all files that have inside this part of text/code

Comment: it is actually like this - 
`Vendor
     Vendor Name`
where `Vendor Name` is dynamically populated

Comment: If you don't find anything using Vendor Name look for css classes around it. If you could paste part of this with html tags from browser console

Comment: Thanks. but I was able to locate it. it is getting added in - `product options` field in Database. 
will see how I can exclude that. thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

Might be worth giving this module & chrome plugin a try, it could be useful in this scenario:

MageSpecialist MSP Dev Tools

https://github.com/magespecialist/m2-MSP_DevTools

This is a Magento 2 module that, when used in conjunction with a chrome plugin, adds some extra stuff into the chrome dev tools so you can pinpoint where things are coming from (amongst other things!)

Once you've installed the module and the chrome plugin, you can right click on the "Vendor Name: Name" and inspect it, then in the Magento tab in the inspector it should tell you what template it comes from, which will tell you which module it's in (see the usage guide on the link above)

If it's not possible to use this, then you could try disabling each of the custom modules you have installed one by one, clearing the cache and refreshing the cart page after each disable. This will give you an idea of which module is adding the code in.

The other option is to search the codebase for any of the html around the text that appears. Depending on how modules were installed (composer / manual) the code will either be in app/code or vendor/ so you will need to search both places for that html.

You could also look for modules by the files being overridden, so any module containing one or more of these files could be a culprit:

```
view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml
view/frontend/email/order_new.html 
view/frontend/email/order_new_guest.html
```